# DNF-Automatic trigger set to run at unconfigured time

Tags: linux, systemd, dnf, systemd-timers

I am configuring dnf-automatic to automatically install security updates on some low priority test boxes. Eventually I want to the updates to run every Sunday morning around 4-5AM, but for testing purposes I've configured the boxes to kick off the update Wed afternoons at 14:xx and minimised any randomisation for now. After being started, the first update does run at it's schedule time, but if I then look at the timer status in systemd, the next schedule time of running is 6am the next day. I understand this is the time that dnf-automatic executes by default which may bear some relation, but I don't see where this is referenced in my config:

```
● dnf-automatic-install.timer - dnf-automatic-install timer
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnf-automatic-install.timer; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dnf-automatic-install.timer.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (waiting) since Wed 2023-12-06 14:45:31 GMT; 20min ago
  **Trigger: Thu 2023-12-07 06:00:02 GMT; 14h left**

Dec 06 14:45:31 dcbutlpocglog5.zonalconnect.local systemd[1]: Started dnf-automatic-install timer.
```

Relevant config files as follows:

```
[root@dcbutlpocglog5 ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/dnf-automatic-install.timer.d/override.conf
[Unit]
Description=dnf-automatic-install timer
# See comment in dnf-makecache.service
ConditionPathExists=!/run/ostree-booted
Wants=network-online.target

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Wed 14:51
RandomizedDelaySec=5s
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target



[root@dcbutlpocglog5 ~]# cat /etc/dnf/automatic.conf
[commands]
upgrade_type = security

[emitters]
emit_via = motd

[install]
upgrade_requirements_on_install = yes
download_updates = yes
apply_updates = yes
gpgcheck = 1
emit_via = motd
random_sleep = 5
reboot = yes
```

Can anybody tell me why this is happening please, and help me prevent the extra updates running outside of what is configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fix found, it seems SystemD timers are additive and an additional blank "OnCalendar="  parameter was needed in front of my own to clear the normal one:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=Wed 14:51
RandomizedDelaySec=5s
Persistent=true
```

Result:

```
[root@dcbutlpocglog5 ~]# systemctl status dnf-automatic-install.timer
● dnf-automatic-install.timer - dnf-automatic-install timer
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnf-automatic-install.timer; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dnf-automatic-install.timer.d
└─override.conf
Active: active (waiting) since Wed 2023-12-06 14:45:31 GMT; 20h ago
**Trigger: Wed 2023-12-13 14:51:03 GMT; 6 days left**
```